# compiling error for include files

Tags: c

I am using turbo C++ compiler but while compiling any program I am getting an error as

> unable to open include file STDIO.H

Same also getting for `conio`. Now, what should I have to do to remove this errors?

Comment: Is it `<#include stdio.h>` or `<#include STDIO.H>`?  From the way your error is worded it's tough to decide one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Your include path is not properly set up. You must look in the settings and point the include path there.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
```

Hope this helps